# why is there a huge gap on my comments page in wordpress using facebook comments?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am a bit new to wordpress and I have researched on how to add facebook comments to my webpage and I have successfully done so, but there is a huge gap between the top of the page and where someone can post a reply. Can anyone help me out and tell me what I have done wrong? I just took my first class on php, so I do know a bit and should understand this, but I feel as if I'm missing something.

Here is the link to the page:

http://theamericanpatriot.co.nf/2013/01/16/test-number-1/#respond

Comment: What plugin or code did you use to add the facebook comments to your site? Can you add that info above? There is a span with a height of 617px that's causing the gap but I'm not sure if that's something you inserted or if it's from the plugin/code you used.

Comment: I am supposed to put this after the <body> tag:

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=587835031231247";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


And this in the comment.php file:

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://theamericanpatriot.co.nf/blog/" data-width="470" data-num-posts="3"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a plugin called "Facebook comments for Wordpress" is creating that gap. You should disable that plugin because you don't need it if you have the code you wrote in your comment above.